# Is there a way to use Pathlib to traverse parents folders until a name matches?

Tags: python, pathlib

I was discussing with a colleague if there is a built-in (or clean) way to use Pathlib to traverse through an arbitrary Path to find a given parent folder, for example the root of your repository (which may differ per user that has a local copy of said repo). I simulated the desired behaviour below:

```
from pathlib import Path

def find_parent(path: Path, target_parent: str) -> Path:
    for part in path.parts[::-1]:
        if part != target_parent:
            path = path.parent
        else:
            break
    return path

path = Path("/some/arbitrarily/long/path/ROOT_FOLDER/subfolder1/subfolder2/file.py")
root = find_parent(path, "ROOT_FOLDER")
assert root == Path("/some/arbitrarily/long/path/ROOT_FOLDER")
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: `while path.name != 'ROOT_FOLDER' and path.parent != path: path = path.parent`? This will iterate up to the root. Finally you need to check if resulting path is not `/` (it will be if directory not found), same as in while condition (`if path == path.parent: raise RuntimeError('Wrong location: make sure you are located in a proper directory'`).

Comment: what deos `assert root == Path` do?

Comment: @Bhargav that is solely to display what I am trying to achieve with this code snippet.

Comment: got it...got it

Comment: Though your solution is OK (besides missing return - it should `return path` instead of `break`). This question would be a better fit for CodeReview SE, because you have working code and wanna know if it can be improved and have no actual problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

You could iterate over [`path.parents`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) (plural) directly, which makes this a bit cleaner:

```py
def find_parent(path: Path, target_parent: str) -> Path | None:
    # `path.parents` does not include `path`, so we need to prepend it if it is
    # to be considered
    for parent in [path] + list(path.parents):
        if parent.name == target_parent:
            return parent
```

(No need for the else clause.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Chris's answer, I found the following one-liner is what I am after:

`root = [parent for parent in path.parents if parent.name == "ROOT_FOLDER"][0]`

---

Updated to `root = next((parent for parent in path.parents if parent.name == "ROOT_FOLDER"), None)` based on @SUTerliakov's suggestion.

Comment: That will fail with an `IndexError` if no parents match

Comment: Using a listcomp to take first element is usually useless: you can use `next(parent for ... if ...)`, will raise `StopIteration`. You can also pass a default value as second argument to `next` to return it instead of raising. Finally, this fails for path already pointing to `ROOT_FOLDER`, same problem as in @Chris answer.

Comment: I updated it to include `next` with a default value of None. The edge case where the path is already the correct path, I will just accept.

Comment: (Also, "one-liners" are generally overrated. If you're typing them in all the time yourself, e.g. in a shell, fine. But for real code, clarity rules.)

Comment: Agreed, but I cannot afford to write this function in every file I need this.

Comment: Then write it once and `import` it :-). That also makes maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: Again, agreed, but the project I am working in would become a lot more messy if I have to make a new directory for such utilities which I only use a handful of times. It's a bit in a gray zone when it comes to how often I use it.